# Using environment variables with Boost Filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a way for Filesystem to understand a path like this one

```
boost::filesystem::exists("%appdata%\somefile");
```

without using other libraries to expand the `%appdata%` part?

Comment: Does the Windows API count as an ‘other library’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want exactly. There is `std::getenv` from `<cstdlib>` which you can check out. More info on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I need :)